# Importing blackboard wedge symbol from `stix` or `boisik`

Tags: symbols, stix

I would like to use this blackboard wedge symbol without switching my current math font. I have found the symbol in both the `stix` and `biotik` package. I have also found numerous questions and answers about how to import specific symbols from packages, but despite that I haven't been able to adapt any of those answers to my spe

[image: bb wedge]

I have found the symbol in both the `stix` and `biotik` package. I have also found numerous questions and answers about how to import specific symbols from packages, but despite that I haven't been able to adapt any of those answers to my specific case.

Would anyone be able to help me, or suggest an alternative?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks henri, but I wasn't able to understand the answers to that question well enough to apply them to my case

Comment: I posted an answer showing you how to do it but the question should be closed as duplicate regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols3}{LS1}{stixbb}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols3}{bold}{LS1}{stixbb}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Wedge}{\mathbin}{symbols3}{"A3}

\begin{document}

$\Wedge$

\end{document}
```

[image]